# self.NavigationController is nil even if called with initWithRootViewController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong here, I have there are other posts about it but they seem related to a more articulate case, in my situation, everything seems very simple, but still it doesn't work.

In my AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = 
            [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

    // Instantiate the window
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;

    // Show the window
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;     
}
```

In MyViewController.m (there is no xib file)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"self.navigationController %@", self.navigationController);
}
```

The result of this is:

```
2012-02-26 22:41:19.366 Test [4488:15203] self.navigationController (null)
```

## EDIT

So, I almost figured out but I haven't understood the reason.

First of all, to better specify, my view controllers were UITableViewControllers, and the problem apparently relies on the initWithStyle method customization I made:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [self initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        [[self tableView] setBackgroundColor:kTableViewBackgroundColor]; 
        [[self tableView] setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
    }
    return self;
}
```

If I comment out the two rows inside the if, i.e. if I do:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        //[[self tableView] setBackgroundColor:kTableViewBackgroundColor]; 
        //[[self tableView] setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
    }
    return self;
}
```

the self.NavigationController gets instantiated properly, otherwise it doesn't. Can someone explain me why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you override the `init` method, it basically means the properties of the super class view controller accessor method, which has the property the navigationController is set to nil, and you have the `tableView` property instantiated instead.

You can set the tableview style and other properties in the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Yes, moving the tableview style to viewDidLoad is what I did now, but are you sure of your statement? When I write: `self = [super initWithStyle:style];` I expect my superclass to be instantiated correctly not nil-led.

Comment: Your super class method will be overridden. The navigation property is not set at all. It is there for nil. On the other hand, the tableView property methods are set.

Comment: I too encounter this same problem, and I'm still not convinced with the answer was correct, since I did not override any init methods. If I access the navigationController property in viewWillAppear then it actually finds the controller correctly...

Answer (score 1):

What's inside your init method? Did you override that method? If not, you probably should or use the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method, from the [Apple Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Returns a newly initialized view controller with the nib file in the specified bundle.

And from the `UIViewController.h` file:

```
/*
  The designated initializer. If you subclass UIViewController, you must call the super implementation of this
  method, even if you aren't using a NIB.  (As a convenience, the default init method will do this for you,
  and specify nil for both of this methods arguments.) In the specified NIB, the File's Owner proxy should
  have its class set to your view controller subclass, with the view outlet connected to the main view. If you
  invoke this method with a nil nib name, then this class' -loadView method will attempt to load a NIB whose
  name is the same as your view controller's class. If no such NIB in fact exists then you must either call
  -setView: before -view is invoked, or override the -loadView method to set up your views programatically.
*/
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
```

Comment: Actually you got very close, maybe you can help me understanding the reason of the solution I just found. I am going to edit my question now. Thanks!